# Better way to change html tags in bottle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, python-2.7, bottle

I am running bottle v .12. I have a function that creates output that I want (with html tags) and returns the value as a string. I want to write that string to an html page, but it replaces my tags with '&lt', '&gt', etc. Right now my solution is to run javascript after the page loads, find those patterns and replaces them. Is there a better way?

example

**functions.py:**

```
def create_html(dict_in):
    output ='<li class="myclass">'
    output +='<div class="class_link">'
    output +='<a href="/showDevice?id='+str(dict_in['_id'])+'">'+dict_in['name']+'&nbsp;</a>'

    return output
```

**template.tpl:**

```
%import lib.functions
<div id="content">
    <div class="device_wrapper">
        %for thing in list_of_things:
            {{lib.functions.create_html(thing)}}
        %end #end for loop
    </div>
</div>
```

**custom.js**

```
$('#change_tags').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var t = $this.text();
    $this.html(t.replace('\"',''));
    $this.html(t.replace('&lt','<').replace('&gt', '>'));

});$
```

tldr; How do I change the tags before bottle changes them? Is there a non-js solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions), you can turn off escaping html by putting an exclamation mark before the expression:

```
%import lib.functions
<div id="content">
    <div class="device_wrapper">
        %for thing in list_of_things:
            {{!lib.functions.create_html(thing)}}
        %end #end for loop
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I must have read through this a number of times, but never saw it. Thanks!